# Private key generation?

Tags: privatekey

What are the technical specifications of a private key?

https://getmonero.org/technical-specs/ doesn't say.

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Private_key shows: "In Bitcoin, a private key is a 256-bit number, which can be represented one of several ways. Here is a private key in hexadecimal - 256 bits in hexadecimal is 32 bytes, or 64 characters in the range 0-9 or A-F. "

I need to generate a private key by coin flipping.

Answer (score 3):

A private spend key is a positive integer lesser than `l = 7237005577332262213973186563042994240857116359379907606001950938285454250989` (which is a 253-bit integer). The usual process to make a private spend key is to generate a random 256-bit integer and then reduce it modulo `l`.

The private spend keys are usually represented in one of the following ways:

- 32 bytes (little-endian order)
- 64 hexadecimal characters
- 25 words (mnemonic seed with 1 checksum word)

You can generate the 256-bit number with coin flips, but then you have to compute its remainder modulo `l`. Also, instead of using a simple coin flip to determine each bit (e.g. 0 for head, 1 for tail), it is better to use double flips to have better randomness in case the coin has a bias (e.g. 0 for head-tail, 1 for tail-head, ignore head-head and tail-tail).

Comment: Awesome tip about the double flips. An article describing why it works is here: http://carlos.bueno.org/2011/10/fair-coin.html